# Is it possible to run XSplit?

Tags: wine, skype, webcam, playonlinux

I want to use XSplit as a webcam in skype, so that I can have 2 people screen-sharing in a meeting. If this is possible, what libraries would be required? I have already tried, but the installer just froze. The logs from PlayOnLinux were no help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize this is not a direct answer to your question, but I'd suggest using something that directly runs on Linux for best results. Using PlayOnLinux adds a layer of emulation as it's using Wine. It is possible that Wine does not implement all the functions needed for webcam use.

I used [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) wit good results. It will allow you to combine various input sources (like webcam, desktop, HTML overlay, etc) into one stream. It's not the most user friendly solution (it's overkill for simple screen sharing), but it definitely gets the job done.

For my use case, I wanted the OBS stream to manifest itself as a webcam. This way, I could use it with Skype. For this, I used a plugin named [obs-v4l2sink](https://github.com/CatxFish/obs-v4l2sink/). This plugin converts the OBS stream into a video4linux software webcam. You should load the video4linux module by going to your terminal and do a `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=1 video_nr=10 card_label="OBS Cam" exclusive_caps=1`. After this, there should be a second webcam named 'OBS Cam' in your video conferencing application. Then start OBS, start the obs-v4l2sink plugin, and you are ready to go!

Comment: I tried this out, but I am just getting the message "format not support". I have tried using different formats.

Comment: Which steps did you take exactly, and what were the results of all the steps? And which step gives the "format not supported" error?

Comment: Sorry, I was using it incorrectly. It now works fine!